# Localized file resource not found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have included these files in my project with *Build Action* set to *Content*:

```
\Resources\Myfolder\Myfiles-de-DE.zip
\Resources\Myfolder\Myfiles-en-US.zip
\Resources\Myfolder\Myfiles-sv-SV.zip
\Resources\Myfolder\Myfiles-fr-FR.zip
```

In my *Package.appxmanifest* I have tried this [when "Open With..." "XML (Text) Editor"]:

```
  <Resources>
    <!--  First = Default  -->
    <Resource Language="en-US" />
    <Resource Language="sv-SV" />
    <Resource Language="de-DE" />
    <Resource Language="fr-FR" />
  </Resources>
```

and this:

```
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
```

In code I am trying to access the file like this:

```
Dim ZipPath As String = "Resources\Myfolder\Myfiles-.zip"
Dim fs As System.IO.Stream = Await _    
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync(ZipPath)
```

**But I get only a FileNotFoundException! What am I doing wrong?**

PS: The file loads if I change the code to this:

```
Dim ZipPath As String = "Resources\Myfolder\Myfiles-en-US.zip"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't fully clear what you're trying to accomplish.  But the code should throw that exception unless you have `Resources\Myfolder\Myfiles-.zip` file loaded in there by default.

I'm guessing you want to load in the specific zip file based on their prefer language, but no where in your code do attempt to get their language.

You can try to do a `LocalizedStrings` : [How to build a localized app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx)

Or you can just get their prefer language and append it to the ZipPath that you have

```C#
string ZipPath = "Resources\Myfolder\Myfiles-" + culture_extention + ".zip";
```

where culture_extention is `Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]`

[image]

Comment: I want to reduce the download size of my app so the download includes only the version of Myfiles-##-##.zip specific to a user's locale. I guess Microsoft calls this appbundle. I should not need to get users language by "hand"; This should be automatic somehow.